# How do I get rid of stale uninstalled entries in dpkg?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I see stale previously uninstalled packages in dpkg:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l *boost*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                      Version           Architecture      
+++-=========================-=================-=================
un  libboost1.42-dev          <none>            <none>
```

However, I cannot remove the entry.

```
$ sudo apt --purge remove libboost1.42-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libboost1.42-dev' is not installed, so not removed

$ sudo dpkg --purge libboost1.42-dev
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libboost1.42-dev which isn't installed
```

Running apt-cache shows:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy libboost1.42-dev
libboost1.42-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libboost1.42-dev`

Comment: Btw, using `sudo dpkg --clear-avail` doesn't work for me.

Comment: @A.B. Yes the old package is still showing up.

Comment: @A.B. What was your answer to my question before it was removed?

Comment: If A.B.'s method doesn't work try this: `sudo dpkg --set-selections <<<"libboost1.42-dev purge"` and then `sudo apt-get purge libboost1.42-dev`

Comment: @kos: tried your method but it didn't work.  After running the 2nd command `apt-get purge`, the package is still showing up.

`$ sudo dpkg --set-selections <<<"libboost1.42-dev purge"`
`dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1: libboost1.42-dev`
`dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database`
`is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method`

Comment: Does it still show up as `un` (*u*nknown - *n*ot installed)? In any case try to install it and purge it: `sudo apt-get install libboost1.42-dev && sudo apt-get purge libboost1.42-dev`

Comment: @kos I think it's too late to install that package, because when I run `apt-get install xx`, it complains that `Package libboost1.42-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source`.

Yes the package is still showing up as an "un".

Comment: Another try: `sudo apt-get update`, perhaps it helps.

Comment: And another try `sudo apt-get install aptitude; sudo aptitude why libboost1.42-dev`

Comment: Ah I didn't notice, then why are we even mentioning `apt-get`? `sudo dpkg -r libboost1.42-dev`

Comment: @A.B. If it's not installed `apt-get` and `aptitude` will do nothing either! ;)

Comment: @kos I have the impression that dpkg and apt are somehow connected -- the data they work on must be consistent.  `$ sudo dpkg -r libboost1.42-dev` doesn't work.

`dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libboost1.42-dev which isn't installed`

Comment: Let's talk in chat @wsw http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: I have the solution for you. Read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `un` in the first column means `unknown` and `not installed`.

In *your special case* it means:

```
Package libboost1.42-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package
```

Why? That's why:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libboost1.42-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libboost1.42-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

---

The solution? There is no solution, it it's by design...

Start a test

```
$ sudo grep -r 'libboost1.42-dev' /var/lib/apt/*
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_wily_main_binary-i386_Packages:Conflicts: bjam, boost-build, libboost1.42-dev, libboost1.46-dev, libboost1.48-dev, libboost1.49-dev, libboost1.50-dev, libboost1.52-dev, libboost1.53-dev, libboost1.54-dev, libboost1.55-dev, libboost1.57-dev
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_wily_main_binary-amd64_Packages:Conflicts: bjam, boost-build, libboost1.42-dev, libboost1.46-dev, libboost1.48-dev, libboost1.49-dev, libboost1.50-dev, libboost1.52-dev, libboost1.53-dev, libboost1.54-dev, libboost1.55-dev, libboost1.57-dev
```

The "problem" is in the two files `/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_wily_main_binary-amd64_Packages` and `/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_wily_main_binary-amd64_Packages`

Lets check one of them: `/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_wily_main_binary-amd64_Packages`

A search for `libboost1.42-dev` gives us a new package `libboost1.58-dev`. Note the list of conflicting packages:

```
Package: libboost1.58-dev
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 102966
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
Original-Maintainer: Debian Boost Team 
Architecture: amd64
Source: boost1.58
Version: 1.58.0+dfsg-3.1ubuntu1
Depends: libstdc++-4.8-dev | libstdc++-dev
Suggests: libboost1.58-doc, libboost-atomic1.58-dev, libboost-chrono1.58-dev, libboost-context1.58-dev, libboost-coroutine1.58-dev, libboost-date-time1.58-dev, libboost-exception1.58-dev, libboost-filesystem1.58-dev, libboost-graph1
.58-dev, libboost-graph-parallel1.58-dev, libboost-iostreams1.58-dev, libboost-locale1.58-dev, libboost-log1.58-dev, libboost-math1.58-dev, libboost-mpi1.58-dev, libboost-mpi-python1.58-dev, libboost-program-options1.58-dev, libboos
t-python1.58-dev, libboost-random1.58-dev, libboost-regex1.58-dev, libboost-serialization1.58-dev, libboost-signals1.58-dev, libboost-system1.58-dev, libboost-test1.58-dev, libboost-thread1.58-dev, libboost-timer1.58-dev, libboost-w
ave1.58-dev, libboost1.58-tools-dev, libmpfrc++-dev, libntl-dev
Conflicts: bjam, boost-build, libboost1.42-dev, libboost1.46-dev, libboost1.48-dev, libboost1.49-dev, libboost1.50-dev, libboost1.52-dev, libboost1.53-dev, libboost1.54-dev, libboost1.55-dev, libboost1.57-dev
Filename: pool/main/b/boost1.58/libboost1.58-dev_1.58.0+dfsg-3.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Size: 6233784
MD5sum: 867f4210133469ec03d6cf882a9b6ad3
SHA1: 39647540966b1eea834dd86e47158e67cf0b2ed6
SHA256: bc427831ec16348cf81f0dd44c889d23d4e70c9fa0f1aadefff0fa77119875cf
Description: Boost C++ Libraries development files
Multi-Arch: same
Homepage: http://www.boost.org/
Description-md5: afccffe6a3ce49022d7832b028860029
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 9m
Task: ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev
```

### And this is the solution or an explanation

The package `libboost1.42-dev` isn't available, check the output of `apt-cache policy libboost1.42-dev`, but is referred by another package, `libboost1.58-dev`, in the list of conflicting packages and that's why you have this item in the output of `sudo dpkg -l *boost*`.

The package `libboost1.58-dev` is in the Ubuntu main repositories and you **could** remove this repository to get rid of the output of the `dpkg …` command. **But that's a really bad idea.**

Comment: So I'll have to live with seeing the stale entry whenever I run `sudo dpkg -l *boost*`.

Comment: Yes, you have to live with it. But I, and many others.